# Require div to expand to contain content even larger than page width

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to have a div stretch to contain the content when the content is larger than the div, even when the content stretches beyond the width of the html page.

Example HTML:

```
<body>
    <div id="outerDiv">
        <div id="innerDiv">asdfasdfkjasdflkjasldkfalsdkfjalsdkflaskdjfaslkdjfkalsjdhfkasjdhkljsdfashdjsdkjasfkjakfjhskdjfhakjdhkasjdhfsjdkashasjhkajsdkashkashfkajsdlfkjaskdjfhaksdjlaskjdkjdfhkasjdkajndckasjdbcjhsadcjkhasbdfhasbfjkasbdkjfnasdkcsdjfnaksjdfbaksdhfiweuhfjskdbfasjdfnasdfasdfasf
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Example CSS:

```
#outerDiv
{
    background-color: red;
}

#innerDiv
{
    background-color: blue;
}
```

I have an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/978ew1jz/4/

I want the blue div to stretch as long as the text does.

Edit:
I also need the red div to still surround the blue div when the blue div stretches.

Comment: is adding `overflow: scroll;` to the blue div and option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your `#outerDiv` CSS to

```
#outerDiv
{
  background-color: red;
  display:inline-block;
  width: auto;
}
```

and it will stretch as per the content.

**EDIT:**

Here is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Sourabh_/978ew1jz/5/). Your `red div` will stretch with the `blue div`.